# Directory protected with .htaccess and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I have a standard WordPress installation at the root of my public_html directory with this .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I would like to protect the directory  /manager which contain an other application with AuthType Basic so my .htaccess look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin Area"
Require valid-user
```

Here is my basic structure:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/manager/.htaccess
/manager/index.php
```

Now, when I try to access /manager directory, I receive a 404 Not Found from my WordPress installation. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have rewriting and password protection enabled I get somme issues like you have got, and adding the folowing two lines to my htaccess file always fix them, try it :

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

**Edit :**

Change this line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

to this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /manager/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: With your solution, I see the authentication box but I always view the 404 not found...

Comment: Hey @Yazmat, thanks for the edit - Android phone nightmare! Rivard, sorry my answer never worked, I was sure that was it. I''ll leave you in Yazmat's hands :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alter your .htaccess in the root to remove the directory /manager from the rewrite rules used by WordPress (which handles everything through index.php)

So you need to add a new rewrite condition in like so;

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/( manager|manager/.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I add the condition RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(manager|manager/.*)$ but I always the 404 not found...